# Performance tuning for jsonb column containing nested json arrays

Tags: postgresql, performance, jsonb

I have a jsonb column in a table with the following model:

```json
{
  "framework": {
    "name": "framework name",
    "sections": [
      {
        "controls": [
          {
            "name": "control name",
            "accounts": [
              {
                "rules": [
                  {
                    "id": 841,
                    "name": "rule name",
                    "entities": [
                      {
                        "id": "entity id",
                        ...
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have a query that requires traversing the above-nested structure and perform filter based on specific values. For that purpose I have used cross join lateral multiple times on the extracted values of the jsonb_array_elements() function. Following is the sample sql query.

```sql
SELECT
    r.rule_sets_id AS ruleSetId,
    ARRAY_AGG(distinct CAST(account->>'accountId' AS text)) AS accountIdsInJsonArray,
    COUNT(distinct control ->> 'name') AS enabledControls,
    COUNT(distinct rule ->> 'id') AS enabledRules
FROM reports r
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(result->'framework'->'sections') AS section
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(section->'controls') AS control
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(control->'accounts') AS account
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(account->'rules') AS rule
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(rule->'entities') AS entity
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT rule_sets_id, max(modified_on) modified_on
    FROM reports
    WHERE workspace_id = :workspaceId
    AND status = 'COMPLETED'
    GROUP BY rule_sets_id
) r1 ON r.modified_on = r1.modified_on AND r.rule_sets_id = r1.rule_sets_id
WHERE r.workspace_id = :workspaceId AND r.status = 'COMPLETED' 
and account ->> 'accountId' in ('123456789012') 
and account ->> 'dataSource' in ('AWS')
GROUP BY r.rule_sets_id;
```

Now for the above query I want to enhance the performance of the same by creating required indexes for the jsonb column. Also, there is currently index on columns `workspace_id`, `status`, `rule_sets_id` on the table `reports`.

Following is the link where I have shared the explain analyze output of the above sql query: https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/66139bc286gbh19c

What can I do to improve performance?

Comment: "*What can I do to improve performance?*" - Normalize the JSON into real columns in the database so they can be indexed properly, FWIW.

Comment: It is already very fast.  How much faster do you need it to be?

Comment: Are all `account->>'accountId'` guaranteed to be unique for every `control ->> 'name'`? If so you can remove the `DISTINCT` from the aggregates and instead aggregate on two levels. Same for `rule ->> 'id'` are there always unique values in different `account`s?

Comment: Have a look at the `@>` operator.